# laravel 5.5 storeAs not work well

Tags: laravel-5

I need to save an image, consider that the image arrive correctly from a request, after that I need to save in storage/app.

Below the code in controller class:

```
public function getImage(ImageRequest $request)
{

      $path = $request->image->storeAs( 'images','img.jpg','local');

}
```

i see this error without nothing saved:

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function storeAs() on null

Answer (score 0):

> Call to a member function storeAs() on null

This error tells you that you are trying to call the storeAs() method on a null object, which means $request->image is null/doesn't exists.